# Store UserTokens generated by ASP.Net Core identity for external login provider

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am using Facebook as external login of ASP.Net Core identity.
I would like, even if the user logged in with Facebook, the user to fill his profile on the website.
For that I use the `ExternalLoginCallback` method, from which I would like to get data from Facebook such as date of birth, location (country), ...

One issue is if the user unchecked some of the permissions, the default call to Facebook fails:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (info == null)
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));

// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
```

I would also need to do some additional checks on user data, which would require calling directly the Graph API.

My blocking points:
- In the `ExternalLoginCallback` method, I would need to separate the 'country' and 'birthday' to avoid the Facebook API to return an error in case of the user didn't grant the permission
- For that I would need the the user access_token (and for additional calls in the method), I don't see how to get it even if it is used by the Facebook Identity framework
- Once the profile created, I would like to get access to this access_token, which should be stored in the UserTokens table (I guess?), but I can't find it there, the table is empty. (my DbContext is a class extending `IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, long>`, don't know if it has an impact)

I have found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670559/4881677 which may help, but not sufficient.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store the user Facebook token, it requires to specify it in the options (not stored by default).

```
var fo = new FacebookOptions();
fo.SaveTokens = true;
```

From there we can call the graph method permissions to get the available permissions: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token={token}`

Then it can be read with something like this:

```
foreach (var perm in data)
{
   perms.Add((string)perm["permission"], (string)perm["status"]);
}
```